# Why did Ayer consider every existential proposition synthetic?

Tags: logic, epistemology, semantics, logical-positivism

> ....For, since existence is not a predicate, to assert that an object exists is always to assert a synthetic proposition....

1. What about math objects? If I say that the triangle with two angles exists, wouldn't that be analytic proposition, although false?
2. How does it follow from the fact that existence isn't a predicate that every existential proposition is synthetic?

There's no more context. Ayer considered this obvious.

Comment: Because we cannot deduce "existence" from the definition; to assert existence of an object we have to rely on some sort of empirical evidence.

Comment: The "mainstream" position wrt math of Logical positivism is that logic and math are devoided of empirical content. See LTL, *Preface*: "I divide all genuine propositions into two classes: those which, in his terminology, concern ‘relations of ideas’, and those which concern ‘matters of fact’. The former class comprises the a priori propositions of logic and pure mathematics, and these I allow to be necessary and certain only because they are analytic." And page 41: "The truths of logic and mathematics are analytic propositions or tautologies."

Comment: For an empiricist there are no abstract objects.

Comment: Can you include a longer quote?

Comment: A math proposition with the external language 'There's a category of sets where the continuum hypothesis is false' is synthetic since it's well-known that there're possible categories of set theories where CH holds and there're other possible categories of set theories where CH doesn't hold. Outside math since you already knew per Ayer there's no ostensive propositions avail to directly assert any existence and existence is not defined as any property, it's always possible that you fail to find or construct any such described object out of the sigma algebra of all the base objects...

Comment: Mathematical "exists" is a turn of phrase that can be interpreted as "is logically non-contradictory" or "follows from axioms". Ayer is talking about the more literal "existence in reality". If we are to claim that a triangle literally exists in some platonic realm then we would need observational information about such a realm. And generally, if existence is not merely a predicate but an assertion that some concept has a matching object in a real domain then we need observational information about such a domain, which can only be synthetic.